# Copy/paste columns based on a user defined list of Col names?

Tags: vba, dynamic, selection

So I found this bit of VBA that works well if I manually input the specific column names into the script, but how to do this by referencing a Dynamic Named List? I'd love to keep a list of column names on another sheet that can be used as the selection criteria. Help?

```
Sub MoveColumns() 'copy paste columns
Dim wsO As Worksheet
Dim wsF As Worksheet
Dim i As Integer

Application.ScreenUpdating = False
Set wsO = Worksheets("RAW")
Set wsF = Worksheets("Final")
myColumns = Array("Col2", "Col1", "col23", "Col5", "Col6")
With wsO.Range("A1:Z1")
    For i = 0 To UBound(myColumns)
        On Error Resume Next
        .Find(myColumns(i)).EntireColumn.Copy Destination:=wsF.Cells(1, i + 1)
        Err.Clear
    Next i
End With
Set wsO = Nothing
Set wsF = Nothing
Application.ScreenUpdating = True
End Sub
```

Comment: `myColumns = Worksheets("SheetName").Range ("A1:A10")` and realize that will return a 2 dimensional array and when referring to it both dimensions must be used.

Comment: Rather than directing it to specific cells A1:A10, how would i direct it to a dynamic Named Range (yes this would be A1:A10, but allows flexibility to later insert more column selections later)

Comment: Do I need to transpose these into a horizontal array?

Comment: you can transpose it if you want.  To do the named range: `ThisWorkbook.Range("rangeName")`

Comment: I'm sorry, I'm still learning this all and not really sure how to integrate this.  Just switching Worksheets for ThisWorkBook? I am getting an error on this.

And for Transpose, you mean its not necessary? Just trying to understand. The User list is vertical, in a column on another sheet.

Comment: Morning, checking to see if you could support?